# HTML.RenderAction not working in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, renderaction

I am trying to use index view to call another view using renderaction, trying to learn ASP.NET Core 6 MVC from some tutorial.

Can anyone please help how to handle this as renderaction not supporting.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'm afraid `HTML.RenderAction` doesn't support .net core project.What you want to get with `HTML.RenderAction`?